# Unable to replace string with back reference using gsub in R

Tags: regex, r

I am trying to replace some text in a character vector using regex in R where, if there is a set of letters inside a bracket, the bracket content is to erplace the whole thing. So, given the input:

```
tst <- c("85", "86 (TBA)", "87 (LAST)")
```

my desired output would be equivalent to `c("85", "TBA", "LAST")`

I tried `gsub("\\(([[:alpha:]])\\)", "\\1", tst)` but it didn't replace anything. What do I need to correct in my regular expression here?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think you want

```
gsub(".*\\(([[:alpha:]]+)\\)", "\\1", tst)
# [1] "85"   "TBA"  "LAST"
```

Your first expression was trying to match exactly one alpha character rather than one-or-more. I also added the ".*" to capture the beginning part of the string so it gets replaced as well, otherwise, it would be left untouched.

Answer (score 2):

```
gsub("(?=.*\\([^)]*\\)).*\\(([^)]*)\\)", "\\1", tst, perl=TRUE)
## [1] "85"   "TBA"  "LAST"
```

You can try this.See demo.Replace by `\1`.

https://regex101.com/r/sH8aR8/38

Comment: Thanks; unfortunately I can't even begin to see how to translate this into R.

BTW I assume this pattern searches anything inside a bracket? I was trying to qualify only those which have only letters in a bracket.

Answer (score 1):

The following would work. Note that white-spaces *within* the brackets may be problematic

```
A<-sapply(strsplit(tst," "),tail,1)
B<-gsub("\\(|\\)", "", A)
```

Answer (score 1):

I like the purely regex answers better.  I'm showing a solution using the **qdapRegex** package that I maintain as the result is pretty speedy and easy to remember and generalize.  It pulls out the strings that are in parenthesis and then replaces any `NA` (no bracket) with the original value.  Note that the result is a list and you'd need to use `unlist` to match your desired output.

```
library(qdpRegex)
m <- rm_round(tst, extract=TRUE)
m[is.na(m)] <- tst[is.na(m)]

## [[1]]
## [1] "85"
## 
## [[2]]
## [1] "TBA"
## 
## [[3]]
## [1] "LAST"
```